# Selecting Checkboxes Based on Value and Parent ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm using Tampermonkey to check checkboxes. The way it's laid out is there's multiple 'Items', each with the same set of checkboxes. I'm trying to have the checkbox pre-selected based on a combination of the checkbox value **and** the ID (or even title, if that's more ideal).

Currently if I use the below, it will select the checkbox but it will do so for Item 1, Item 2, Item 3 and so on when I need to select different options for each. I'm trying to figure out how I go about narrowing the selection based on the ID (122) or even the title (Item 1)?

```
$("input:checkbox[value='See Notes']").attr("checked", true);
```

This is what my HTML looks like for each item:

```
<div class="field tabular">
  <span class="item-data">{"Id":"122"}</span>
  <div class="field-content">
    <div class="title" title="Item 1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="data">
      <div class="errors"></div>
      <div class="control">
        <div class="option">
          <input id="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option0" type="checkbox" value="Checked & Okay">
          <label for="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option0">Checked & Okay</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
          <input id="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option1" type="checkbox" value="Repair Required">
          <label for="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option1">Repair Required</label>
        </div>
        <div class="option">
          <input id="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option2" type="checkbox" value="See Notes">
          <label for="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option2">See Notes</label>
        </div>
    <!-- Etc... -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$('[title="Item 1"]')                                 //Select elemements with attribute title="Item 1"
       .next()                                        //Select the next element, which is div with class .data
       .find("input:checkbox[value='" + value + "']") //Find checkbox with the value
       .prop("checked", true);                        //Set the prop checked to true
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
var item = 'Item 1';
var value = 'See Notes';

$('[title="' + item + '"]').next().find("input:checkbox[value='" + value + "']").prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field tabular">
  <span class="item-data">{"Id":"122"}</span>
  <div class="field-content">
    <div class="title" title="Item 1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="data">
      <div class="errors"></div>
      <div class="control">

        <div class="option">
          <input id="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option0" type="checkbox" value="Checked & Okay">
          <label for="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option0">Checked & Okay</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input id="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option1" type="checkbox" value="Repair Required">
          <label for="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option1">Repair Required</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input id="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option2" type="checkbox" value="See Notes">
          <label for="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option2">See Notes</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div class="field tabular">
  <span class="item-data">{"Id":"123"}</span>
  <div class="field-content">
    <div class="title" title="Item 2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="data">
      <div class="errors"></div>
      <div class="control">

        <div class="option">
          <input id="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option0" type="checkbox" value="Checked & Okay">
          <label for="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option0">Checked & Okay</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input id="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option1" type="checkbox" value="Repair Required">
          <label for="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option1">Repair Required</label>
        </div>

        <div class="option">
          <input id="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option2" type="checkbox" value="See Notes">
          <label for="checkbox_3668-1523196351429_option2">See Notes</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help @user3189139