# Setting the value of a Dropdown associated with an id node in the same HTML section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm looking to select a specific dropdown value from dozens of HTML dropdowns for a userscript. Is there a way to do this using the ID I have (`{"Id":"302"}`)?

I've tried selecting all items based on the class as a jumping off point but I'm not having much success. Ideally though if I could select based on the provided ID it would allow me to be more specific with the selections.

What I have:

```
waitForDropdown (".control:has(option[value='See Notes'])", selectDropdown);

function selectDropdown (jNode) {
    var evt = new Event ("click");
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);

    jNode.val('See Notes');

    evt = new Event ("change");
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="field tabular">
    <span class="item-data">{"Id":"302"}</span>
    <div class="field-content">
        <div class="title" title="Dropdown A">Dropdown A</div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="errors"></div>
            <div class="control">
                <select>
                    <option value="Not Checked" selected="selected">Not Checked</option>
                    <option value="Checked &amp; Cleaned">Checked &amp; Cleaned</option>
                    <option value="Not Applicable">Not Applicable</option>
                    <option value="See Section Notes">See Notes</option>
                </select>
    <!-- Etc... -->
```

Could I use the title to narrow the selection? Or would the ID make more sense?

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you saying you want to narrow it down via `"Id":"302"`?  If so, is 302 a known stable value? ... Also `waitForDropdown` is not defined and the `value` selector does not match any option `value` (Precise rules apply).

Comment: Apologies @BrockAdams. Hopefully this clarifies. What I'm looking for is to select a value for the dropdown based on the ID ("Id":"302"). 302 is a known stable value. What I've been playing with is:

`$("div.control select").val("Checked & Good");`

However I'd like to make it more specific to either "Id":"302" or even potentially "Dropdown A" but I'm having trouble adding additional selectors in this case.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like [**this other question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718885/selecting-checkboxes-based-on-value-and-parent-id).  Are you Coworkers?  Students in the same class? Sock puppets? ... (Although the approach in this question has the potential to be more robust, esp if the page is ajax-driven.)

Comment: We are indeed working on the same project for work. Is there resources you'd suggest looking at for selecting the title `Dropdown A` to be combined with `div.control select` given the way the title is nested? I've been poking at this for a couple hours now without much success.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks. I'll continue trying things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: `"Could I use the title to narrow the selection? Or would the ID make more sense?"`

A stable, numerical id is *usually* your best bet.  Title, or other, text is subject to: editing or translation/internationalization.  But if the id changes from page to page, or from page reload; don't use it.

There are several problems with that code:

1. `waitForDropdown()` is neither standard nor defined.  **Questions should contain [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).**
   In this case, it looks like a possible version of `waitForKeyElements` -- which is now common, standard, and battle tested.
2. The selector: `option[value='See Notes']`  does not match any of the HTML.
   Refer to [the jQuery Attribute selectors docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).
3. `jNode.val('See Notes');` is attempting to set an invalid value.
4. `jNode.val('See Notes');` is operating on a `<div class="control">`.  It needs to operate on the `<select>`.

Anyway, [the companion question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718885/selecting-checkboxes-based-on-value-and-parent-id) illustrates a top-down tree traversal to get the right nodes.  So, here, I will illustrate a bottom up approach.  It is also **AJAX aware**, unlike that other answer.
Refer to [the jQuery Tree Traversal docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Here is **a complete userscript** that show how to discriminate options based on an associated node/id. (The userscript is just the first gray block):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Set <select> value under specific HTML section id
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements (".control > select > option[value$='Cleaned']", selectId302Value);

function selectId302Value (jNode) {
    //-- Make sure control belongs to the correct id:
    var idNode  = jNode.closest (".field-content").prev (".item-data");
    if (idNode.length === 0) {
        console.error ("Page structure changed or invalid in selectId302Value().");
        return;
    }
    if (idNode.text ().includes ('"302"') ) {
        var evt     = new Event ("click");
        jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);

        //-- Correct val already determined by WFKE selector.
        jNode.parent ().val(jNode.val () );

        //-- The select node would get any required change event.
        evt         = new Event ("change");
        jNode.parent ()[0].dispatchEvent (evt);
    }
}
```

```html
<!----------------------------------------
----- Simulated target page follows: -----
----------------------------------------->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//greasyfork.org/scripts/2199-waitforkeyelements/code/waitForKeyElements.js"></script>
<div class="field tabular">
    <span class="item-data">{"Id":"302"}</span>
    <div class="field-content">
        <div class="title" title="Dropdown A">Dropdown A</div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="errors"></div>
            <div class="control">
                <select>
                    <option value="Not Checked" selected="selected">Not Checked</option>
                    <option value="Checked &amp; Cleaned">Checked &amp; Cleaned</option>
                    <option value="Not Applicable">Not Applicable</option>
                    <option value="See Section Notes">See Notes</option>
                </select>
    </div></div></div>

    <span class="item-data">{"Id":"777"}</span>
    <div class="field-content">
        <div class="title" title="Dropdown B">Dropdown B</div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="errors"></div>
            <div class="control">
                <select>
                    <option value="Not Checked" selected="selected">Not Checked</option>
                    <option value="Checked &amp; Cleaned">Checked &amp; Cleaned</option>
                    <option value="Not Applicable">Not Applicable</option>
                    <option value="See Section Notes">See Notes</option>
                </select>
    </div></div></div>
</div>
```

Run the code snippet to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks Brock! This is very thorough and I'll be sure to make my questions more clear going forward.

Comment: I've run in to an issue with this. The events to click and change the dropdown values fire fine, however these fields are on a form and when I go to save the form the newly selected values are ignored. Only the values selected via manual click and select will save with their new values.

Comment: First try the updated code, but that's beyond the scope of this question because neither the actual target page nor an MCVE were provided. ...  See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site) for help if additional tuning is needed.  If you get stymied, open a new question but it must either link to the target page or provide an MCVE.